# Barcode scan event?

Tags: events, barcode, barcode-scanner, code39

I have a simple USB barcode reader which I intend to use to scan COD 39 barcodes. I know that just scanning the barcode while having a text field on focus will get me the text input of the barcode I'm scanning. However my requirement is a bit different.

I need to create a C# application where upon reading a barcode it will check the read barcode with a list I have to see whether it exists. The problem is I cannot keep a text box on my app in focus all the time as the app does other things as well. Instead what I want is for my program to keep looking for some sort of "event" which will be raised once the bar code scanners scans a code.

So does anyone know if there is such an event which will be raised when the barcode is scanned some code so I can instruct my program to do the rest of the work when the scanners scans a barcode?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the scanner would've come with some kind of SDK or library that you could use.

Less ideally, you may have to resort to reading it as if it's a serial port.

Actually, you should probably read the following link instead. as I was looking up how to do that, I ran into a similar post already on StackOverflow with a similar answer.

[Reading from an USB barcode scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001543/reading-from-an-usb-barcode-scanner)

Comment: Edgar, it is, sadly is not a device that comes with a SDK library. It hardly had any documentation even. I will see what I can do. Thanks!