# barcode scan event in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, barcode-scanner, jquery-events

I am using PHP5...I need to use barcode scanner for some functionality.
On scan of every barcode am fetching value from database which is already stored.
I am using ajax for that.
My problem is that am not getting which jquery event i have to use to achieve this?

I tried blur function. But I need to take curser out every time which may be inconvenient for user.
I tried keyup event which is taking first number of barcode which is not usefull.
Next i used this [Jquery plugin](https://github.com/iuyes/jQuery-Scanner-Detection) which also taking first number of barcode.

In [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001543/reading-from-an-usb-barcode-scanner) they advising to use .net drivers . but i am using PHP 5 /CakePHP 2.10.
Please guide me with this.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i thnk that scanner automatically add an `Enter` keystroke to the end. maybe you could use key-up-event and check for the key-code of enter. Or you could check for a minimum-length of the input before querying.

Comment: @wayneOS yes you are right . ENTER is the event triggering after scan. And i referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895171/prevent-users-from-submitting-a-form-by-hitting-enter this . its working me fine now and your suggestion helped me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You Should consult your barcode scanner manufacturer, The enter function can be remove

Comment: This should be a comment (which I know you can't do) but may get downvoted as a non-answer.

Comment: @gen if its the possibility is true then valid only when you use one scanner. But different user may use different scanner so not valid

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of @wayneOS ... I solved this as follows.
Am posting it because it may be helpfull

```
 $("#myid").keydown(function (event) {
       if(event.keyCode == 13) {
       var myid= $("#myid").val();

        //Calling ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {myid: myid},
            url: "<?php echo "myurl; ?>",
            success: function (data) {
            alert("success");                    
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("1st ajax error");
            }
        });
        $("#myid").val('');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
        }            
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I configured the scanners in a way, so it adds a tab at the end of a scan. After this you only need to check the characters on keyup. If it is a tab, trigger the function you want.